# A thought experiment involving measuring the spins of entangled electrons (one measured inside a black hole)

Tags: black-holes, quantum-entanglement

Suppose two electrons are entangled with opposite spins. Electron #1 passes through the event horizon of a black hole, together with Laboratory Assistant #1. Suppose the assistant measures electron #1's spin after they pass through the event horizon (according to #1's [proper] time) and measures a $+$ spin.

Another laboratory assistant, #2, outside the black hole, watches the Assistant #1 falling into the black hole, but #2 never sees #1 cross the event horizon. After a time, suppose Assistance #2 measure the spin of electron #2. He measures $+$ or $-$.

If Assistant #2 measures $+$, then electron #1 must be $-$. And yet, Assistant #1 (in his proper time) already measured $+$!

It seems to me the "answer" is probably that when #1 makes his measurement inside the BH, he is no longer within the same spacetime as #2. He is *not* in #2's universe. Hence, the entanglement is effectively severed once #1 enters the BH (which #2 never sees), since #2 has no access to #1's spacetime.

Therefore, both electrons can have a spin measurement of $+$.

Assistant #2 never sees #1's measurement, so the issue here is meaningless to him. The interior of the BH is not in #2's spacetime.

HOWEVER, Assistant #1 can see #2's measurement, especially if he has a long time to relax and wait before reaching the BH singularity. #1 can measure $+$, and then after a while he can observe that #2 also measured $+$. Therefore, #1 can witness that the entanglement was broken.

Comment: Why are you claiming a definitive answer? You didn't even properly state any question. If Assistant #1 measures +, then Assistant #2 has to measure -. Assistant #2 will never measure +. Assistant #2 will only just be able to deduce that Assistant #1 measured + but never get to verify. That is fine, it has no meaningful physical information.

Comment: You're missing the point. #2 never sees #1 cross the event horizon; therefore, in #2's spacetime, #1 never made a measurement. Hence, #2 CAN obtain + or -.

But #1 may already have made a measurement in his propert time, say +. And #2 could also measure +.

But forget about #2 now, because he never sees #1 cross the event horizon. BUT #1 can measure + inside the black hole, and then ALSO see that #2 measured +. Therefore, #1 can observe that the entanglement was broken.

Comment: This is the question. One can only speculate that the resolution has to do with the fact that spatial and time coordinates are reversed inside the BH?

Comment: And since whenever there are experiments pitting QM and GR, QM wins, so we need to also begin by assuming that QM will win and thus always uphold the entanglement rather than it getting broken. Also, this can really be weakened---there is no upside to GR to unilaterally break the entanglement, so why should it violate QM for no benefit? There is thus no good reason to expect that the event horizon should do that. Not to mention that there is no physics that depends upon the EH. There is no singularity there, etc.

Comment: If QM and entanglement "wins", then the paradox becomes how can #1 see a + measurement on both electrons. And if we maintain this is impossible, then we must assume that #2 measures a "-" 100% of the time. But how does #2 explain that, when he sees #1 forever approaching the BH and *never* having made a measurement?

Comment: As I said, #2 will always measure -. #2 will just not be able to check his answer, and there is no physical reason why he should be able to, nor care. There is no physical information that can be extracted out of #2 making his measurement.

Comment: My error in stating that "#2 measures a "-" 100% of the time." Of course, the experiment cannot be repeated (that is, #1 will obtain either + or - when he makes a measurement). So, indeed, neither of them will ever know that anything unusual has happened.

The only "paradox" that remains is that this scenario is even more unusual than entanglement across a spacelike interval. In this case, #2 must obtain a "-" even though he can watch #1 forever approach the event horizon (not knowing that in #1's proper time he has actually made a measurement).

Comment: There is no paradox or anything. It is only fun to consider, but not informative. And it can be repeated: assistants #1 and #2 can initially have 1000 pairs of entangled spins to individually measure later. #2 will just get a string of measurements that he would be able to verify that they are 100% anti-correlated to #1's measurements. Actually less unusual than normal entanglement because the weirdness to entanglement is in being able to later compare the results and see correlations, and here there will not be comparisons.

Comment: *"HOWEVER, Assistant #1 can see #2's measurement"* This is not true; there is no overlap in #1 and #2's future lightcones.

Comment: As Aiden notes below, #1 will see #2's measurement. As #1 approaches the EH, it sees the entire future outside the BH. Therefore, if #2 measures the spin of electron #2 any time during his lifetime, #1 will see it before he reaches the EH.

Answer (score 1):

I will focus on the relativity side of this question as the electron spins are discussed in the comments above. In the system described, assistant #2 will measure the spin of the electron **before** assistant #1. The infalling assistant #1 will reach the singularity in finite proper time and can thus perform their measurement from inside the horizon. However, it takes an infinite amount of coordinate time for assistant #1 to cross the event horizon. So assistant #1 would see assistant #2 aging faster and faster as they approach the event horizon, and if assistant #2 is ever in their lifetime going to measure the electron, assistant #1 would see that too before they cross the horizon.

From the perspective of assistant #2, assistant #1's clock slows as they fall and almost stops as they approach the event horizon. So when assistant #2 decides to make their measurement, assistant #1 will still be hanging out near the event horizon (very much redshifted).

No correlation is broken in the spin measurements. If the electron pair was in the singlet state:

$$|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|\uparrow\downarrow\rangle-|\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\right)$$

then the assistants will make perfectly anti-correlated measurements. It's just that assistant #2 will have to measure before #1, and assistant #1 will make their measurement long after assistant #2 has died.